# Binding a TextBlock to a Window's Property

Tags: wpf, binding

This should be simple, yet I can't get it to work.
I have a window (main xaml app window)

I've defined a propery of type "Test" (who has and int ID and DateTime TestDate)

```
public Test CurrentTest
{
    get => currentTest
    set
    {
        currentTest = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTest");
    }
}
```

I've added the OnPropertyChanged Impl:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
private void OnPropertyChanged(String property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

and now I try to bind it to a text block on the window.
But it doesn't work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource CurrentTest}, Path=TestDate, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy, TargetNullValue=Not Yet Set}"></TextBlock>
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding ElementName="CurrentTest" Path="TestDate" TargetNullValue="not yet set" Mode="OneWay"></Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

What should I do to have the textBlock show the Date of this property ?

Comment: I think you know how to set the DataContext right, however beside the implementation of the propertychanged code do you have this behind your class? : INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Also have you checked the outputwindow for specific Binding Errors?

Comment: you where right about INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the RelativeSource property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTest.TestDate,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                         AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Comment: This one works, but it only worked once I've added the INotifyPropertyChanged to the Window class - so thanks @SilverMind as well !

Comment: @Dani, why do you think it should? StaticResource is used to access a resource, not a property of your view...

Comment: This answer works w/o having to implement INotifyPropertyChanged